# "Non numeric argument to binary operator" Error In R

Tags: r

Hello I'm new for R and can help me.

error massage "Error in head(T[rowss, (i + 1)]) - head(T[rowss, i]) : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

code bellow here

```
library("xlsx")  #import library
T <- read_excel("D:/Education/UOR Lecture/Project/4/NEW.xlsx")  #read xlsx file
View(T)
fun <- function(T,rowss) {
rows <- nrow(T)
columns <- ncol(T)
t <- 3
H <- 15.8
last <- 0
for (i in 3:columns-1){
k <- (head(T[rowss,(i+1)])-head(T[rowss,i]))/(head(T[rowss,(i+1)])*t*(H-head(T[rowss,(i+1)])))
last <- k+last
}
fun <- last/columns
return(fun)
}
```

T is a table read from excel sheet
and i also using class function for make sure all are numeric and all are numeric expect T and using class function for T  show `class(T) [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"`

please Help

Comment: To make this reproducible, could you try `dput(head(name_of_data_frame))` and edit your question with the output? `name_of_data_frame` should be whatever you store the result for `read_excel`...I would recommend avoid using `T` (used for `TRUE`) and call it something else...and how are you intending to call your function `fun`?

Answer (score 0):

This error [occurs when you addition, division, or a similar mathematical operator with a non-numeric variables](http://www.modernstatisticswithr.com/errorchapter.html#non-numeric-argument-to-a-binary-operator). In your case, it seems that either `head(T[rowss, (i + 1)])` or `head(T[rowss, i])` is non-numeric. Have a look at the data frame `T` using e.g. `str(T)` to see which of you variables that aren't numeric (e.g. those that are `character` variables).

Comment: I try it using class function but all are numeric
And i use T for the excel sheet get to the R

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all who helped me.
i find the error `for (i in 3:columns-1)` rewrite `for (i in 4:columns-1)` and its work